# OpenCV/Python - In which frame position is video_capture object left when video_cap.read() fails?

Tags: python, opencv, video

I'm writing a script to retrieve some frame sequences from a video, so I'm going through the whole video sequentially and selecting the needed ones.
This is done in subsequent function calls, so I'm using a variable to track the frame position through the video,the overall thing looks like:

```py
def get_required_frames(frames_id_range: list, current_video_frame_counter: int, video_cap) -> Tuple[List[Any], int]:
    selected = []
    while True:
        ret, frame = video_cap.read()
        # if some frames in video cannot be read, return empty list for this shot
        if not ret:
            return [], current_video_frame_counter
        # collect frames in selected range
        if current_video_frame_counter in frames_id_range:
            selected.append(frame)
        # frame successfully read -> update frame position in current video
        current_video_frame_counter += 1
        # after selected range, stop loop
        if current_video_frame_counter > frames_id_range[-1]:
            break
    return images, current_video_frame_counter

# each time this function is called to get the frames I need
selected_frames, current_video_frame_counter = get_required_frames(frames_id_range, current_video_frame_counter, video_capture)
```

Everything works, but I'm not sure about how OpenCV deals with the cases when

```
ret, frame = video_cap.read()
```

returns False (which, for some of my videos, happens quite often).
As you can see, at the moment in my code I'm incrementing the current_video_frame_counter only when ret=True, because after a successful read the video moves on to the following frame. But what happens if ret=False? Does the video move on to the following frame as well? In this case, I should increment the current_video_frame_counter after each read, so something like

```
ret, frame = video_cap.read()
current_video_frame_counter += 1
[...]
```

Hope my question is clear, maybe this helps:
[image]

Comment: undefined. if the docs promise it, you could demand it (bug report). if they don't, you could demand that such a declaration be made in the docs. if you really need to, your only option is to spelunk in the source -- cv::VideoCapture is messy. for the level of control you need (and read() *failing intermittently!*), you really should ditch it. I'd recommend that you either use [PyAV](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV) and wrangle the ffmpeg APIs yourself, or try [imageio](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), or perhaps there's a split or a new project dealing with video I/O specifically?

Comment: found a ["videoio" package](https://github.com/vguzov/videoio), but it's dead. -- there's ["scikit-video"](https://github.com/scikit-video/scikit-video) but that's *even deader*. -- moviepy seems popular but I have no idea if that's a cruddy ffmpeg subprocess or actually using the ffmpeg library... or if it's for "video filters" only, or if it can seek and give you single frames reliably. its `get_frame` seems to imply frame-accurate seeking but it doesn't deliver reliably... that's hard in general. might as well use PyAV directly.